# webpack не обновляет страницу

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

Есть проект на react, все настроено, у других разрабов все работает, у меня почемуто не обновляет страницу при изменений кода, в чем может быть проблема?

package.json

```js
{
  "name": "sport_react",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.5.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.2",
    "babel-plugin-import": "^1.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-async-functions": "^6.8.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.8.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-regenerator": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "webpack": "^1.12.13",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "antd": "^2.8.0",
    "aphrodite": "^1.2.5",
    "axios": "^0.15.0",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-async-functions": "^6.8.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-regenerator": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.9.0",
    "compression": "^1.6.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "dotenv": "^4.0.0",
    "if-env": "^1.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "jsx-to-string": "^1.0.2",
    "md5": "^2.1.0",
    "moment": "^2.13.0",
    "react": "^15.6.2",
    "react-big-calendar": "^0.12.3",
    "react-date-picker": "^5.3.28",
    "react-datetime": "^2.8.10",
    "react-dnd": "^2.1.4",
    "react-dnd-html5-backend": "^2.1.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.2",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.5",
    "react-router": "^2.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.1",
    "react-scripts": "^0.9.5",
    "react-webcam": "^0.2.0",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.0",
    "redux-form": "^5.3.2",
    "redux-form-validation": "0.0.8",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "segmentize": "^0.4.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build --env=production",
    "test_build": "react-scripts build --env=testing",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js

```js
var webpack = require('webpack');
module.exports = {
    entry: ['babel-polyfill', './src/index.js'],
    plugins: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? [
        new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
    ] : [],
    output: {
        path: './public/js',
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/js'
    },
    watch: true,
    watchOptions:{
        aggregateTimeout:100
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader?presets[]=es2015&presets[]=react'},
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style!css" }
        ]
    },
    devtool:"inline-source-map"
};
```

Настройки Webstorm'а смотрел, вроде все нормально, даже если обычными блокнотами сохраняю все равно не работает

Comment: кажется у вас не указаны настройки для webpack-dev-server hot опции и react hmr, это можно скопировать с бойлерплейтов react webpack hmr boiler -> google, их много

Comment: Вроде все настроено, у других разрабов работает, как я понимаю сдесь используется babel-loader, зачем мне другую добавлять

Comment: Babel только транспилирует новый синтаксис в старый, плюс плагины могут что-то делать. Но обновлять страницу автоматически можно если настроен девсервер и react-hmr. Но если у других работает, то я не знаю. Наверное всё это прописано в стартовом скрипте

Comment: когда в терминале webpack-dev-server делаю, выходят много ошибок вроде этого https://yadi.sk/i/MDkPZzns3Pfvz8 , в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Судя по указанной ошибке, бабел не понимает синтаксис ... (деструктурирование объектов). Нужен этот плагин https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-es2015-destructuring/ 
Хотя я бы лучше подключил stage-0 (или 1 или 2), они должны всё это иметь в себе. https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-0/